# Intersection throws com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.TopologyException: Found null DirectedEdge

Tags: java, union, jts-topology-suite

When I make union of 379202 `List<Polygon> rectangles` rectangles and execute intersection with bounds `UnaryUnionOp.union(rectangles).intersection(bounds)` then I get:

```
com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.TopologyException: Found null DirectedEdge
    at com.vividsolutions.jts.geomgraph.EdgeRing.computePoints(EdgeRing.java:139)
    at com.vividsolutions.jts.geomgraph.EdgeRing.<init>(EdgeRing.java:68)
    at com.vividsolutions.jts.operation.overlay.MaximalEdgeRing.<init>(MaximalEdgeRing.java:65)
    at com.vividsolutions.jts.operation.overlay.PolygonBuilder.buildMaximalEdgeRings(PolygonBuilder.java:104)
    at com.vividsolutions.jts.operation.overlay.PolygonBuilder.add(PolygonBuilder.java:78)
    at com.vividsolutions.jts.operation.overlay.PolygonBuilder.add(PolygonBuilder.java:67)
    at com.vividsolutions.jts.operation.overlay.OverlayOp.computeOverlay(OverlayOp.java:256)
    at com.vividsolutions.jts.operation.overlay.OverlayOp.getResultGeometry(OverlayOp.java:189)
    at com.vividsolutions.jts.operation.overlay.OverlayOp.overlayOp(OverlayOp.java:92)
    at com.vividsolutions.jts.operation.overlay.snap.SnapIfNeededOverlayOp.getResultGeometry(SnapIfNeededOverlayOp.java:96)
    at com.vividsolutions.jts.operation.overlay.snap.SnapIfNeededOverlayOp.overlayOp(SnapIfNeededOverlayOp.java:58)
    at com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry.intersection(Geometry.java:1338)
```

Union of rectangles:
[image]

Bounds for intersection:
[image]

Why do I get the exception for the intersection? How to investigate the problem?

Comment: Try if you can find the problematic geometry. Cut your list from the middle and test the first half, then the other. Hopefully the failure is still there and you can go on and split the failing half again.

Comment: Checking, it may be not because of union. Edited question. Will clarify later.